# Sudden Increase in "Blocked from robots"

Tags: google-search-console, robots.txt

In the Index Status section of Google Webmaster Tools a site I manage has seen a sudden increase in pages "Blocked from robots".

[image: Index Status - Blocked from robots]

There's been no spike in Crawl Errors since this happened a week and a half ago, so how can I best diagnose this? Is there any way to find a list of the blocked URLs? Is there a reason this spiked suddenly?

Answer (score 2):

I cannot see any options in Google Webmaster Tools. Unfortunately, Google does not seem to give a clue. At first I thought that the Blocked URLs and testing your robots.txt file would give details, but I am not seeing it. Then I thought perhaps Index Status data could help but no go.

I looked to other tools like Screaming Frog and it is not clear if it will list issues with URLs and the robots.txt file. There is a whole section for the robots.txt file, but I am not sure how deep it will go.

Sorry. This should be a feature in Google Webmaster Tools. Perhaps the test button should list all know URLs that would be blocked.

Comment: I know what's in the robots.txt file. I'm just trying to get a list of URLs the Google is suddenly reporting as blocked when it wasn't before.

Comment: It may not give you a list of URLs unless you specify files, but it should give you an indication in the form of a directory or some other structure of what Google is talking about. As far as Google is concerned that is as close as you get- that I know of. The *blocked from robots* should be referring to the robots.txt file.

Comment: I know this means the robots.txt file, but that's had the same directories blocked for months. How can I tell what 800 URLs are being blocked that weren't before?

Comment: Does the download chart data button in the index status help? No. Sorry. I am still looking.

Comment: Nope, it just lists the number of links of each type by date - https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpbLI.png

Comment: Yeah. I am sorry. As it appears, the test button only seems to be checking the root directory. I did some fiddling around to see if I could get that data and I am not finding anything. Sorry.

Comment: I updated the answer. I was of no real help to you. I am sorry about that. I thought the *test* button in the Blocked URLs was more detailed than it turns out to be. Again, I thought I had an answer- but as it turns out, the feature I was relying on was of no use.

Comment: @closetnoc Sometimes the only answer is that it doesn't exist (yet), which is an acceptable answer too. Google Product Forums are a good place to post these kinds of questions, where they might get reviewed for updates.

Comment: @dan I just could not believe (somehow) that Google would miss such an opportunity. But then again, I have to remind myself that *it is* Google we are talking about. They can do something fantastic and forget an obvious detail. But the fantastic is still worth the price of admission.